# How to bind WPF window title to a viewmodel property and to a static resource property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my WPF application, I have a window whose title is a 2 word string. First word, i need to bind to a ViewModel property and second word, I need to get from resource file as i need to apply localization to that word.

I am not sure how to bind these two different things in the window title. I want something like the below one.

```
<Window Title= "Viewmodel Property + static resource property">
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `MultiBinding` like that.

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.Title>
      <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} {1}">
         <Binding Path="ViewModelProperty"/>
         <Binding Source="{x:Static local:YourStaticProperty}"/>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Window.Title>
   ...
</Window>
```